# Javascript PHP posting with onclick on its value

Tags: javascript, php

I have this div to be passed to another page through form post

```
<div class="temp-shake-2" id="em_1" onclick="this.className=this.className.replace(\"temp-\",\"\");var x = document.getElementById(\"em_1\");var y = x.parentNode; document.getElementById(\"em_1\").remove();y.appendChild(x);">
    HELLO
</div>
```

What it does is when you click on the div it replaces its class from "temp-shake-2" to "shake-2" then removes itself saves it to a variable and appends itself again to its parent. It is working from the original page. Now when i need to preview it to another page through this process:

1. Append the div to a textarea
2. Submit the form that contains the textarea
3. Read the post from the next page through `$_POST['textareaname']`

The `onclick` attribute is being removed. I think this is a browser security due xss but how can I bypass this?

Comment: Please don't use JavaScript in your HTML like that. If you separate your code it will be easier to use and reuse.

Comment: Sorry but i need it there. This will be outputted in an epub so I will not add functions in the xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
//<![CDATA[
// never write `document or `document.body` again
// you should never have to use `window.`anything it's implicit
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
// never use `document.getElementById()` again
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
function ajx(method, url, sendText, responseId){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest || new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  var v = encodeURI(sendText);
  x.open(method, url);
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-length', v.length);
  x.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'close');
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
    E(responseId).innerHTML = x.responseText;
  }
  x.send(v); 
}
var tA = E('textAreaId');
E('em-1').onclick = function(){
  this.className = this.className.replace(/^temp-/, '');
  var ta = tA.value = this.innerHTML;
  ajx('POST', 'yourURL.php', tA.name+'='+ta, 'responseId');
}
//]]>
```

Don't forget XHML should be encased with `CDATA` tags.